# What is the easiest AWS service one can use to deduplicate SNS requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

The [SNS Faq](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/) clearly states that deduplication must be built into each user's application when using SNS.

The first thought that comes to mind is a simple DynamoDB table with expiring entries using a unique identifier from each SNS request and using that as the hash index for the table.

But I'm wondering if there are any more elegant ways of solving this problem? As someone who doesn't have a fully intimate knowledge of all of AWS' services I'd like to ask what other people have envisioned as good solution to this problem.

Some kind of super-fast cache would be the most performant but then you have to worry about cache expiration timing and I can't seem to find any docs which state the percentage of receiving a duplicated SNS request over time to know when to expire said cache.

Comment: Isn't that FAQ entry about deduplication on receiving side?

Comment: @Dunedan yes which AWS service on the receiving side would you incorporate into an application to deduplicate received SNS messages.

Comment: That would depend on what the application does.

Comment: I think DynamoDB with TTL or Redis with TTL would be good options. Depending on your architecture, there might also be options for SQS FIFO with exactly-once delivery.

Comment: What's your use case for having an application receiving SNS messages hosted on AWS? That sounds like something like SQS could be a better fit.

Comment: We use SNS to send trivial JSON messages between microservices. Two examples are a user notification service and an email service. If you want to generate a user notification you send an SNS message to the notification service and the same for email.

Our notification service already has a dynamodb to track notifications so deduplication via dynamo is easy. 

But our email service is fully stateless and has no such back-end architecture so I'm wondering if there might be a better service suited for the job than dynamo for deduplication of the SNS events.

Comment: Thanks @Jarmod I will look into Redis with TTL.